# Save method not work in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I trying to update records so I use `save()` method, but record cannot update in database.

this is my code :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        } else {
            $a = Users::find($id)->save($request->all());
        }

        return redirect()->to('admin/users/'.$id);
    }
```

What is the problem ?

P.S: create method work without problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `update()` method instead:

```
Users::where('id', $id)->update($request->except(['_method', '_token']));
```

Or try to use `fill()` to manually fill the data:

```
$a = Users::find($id)->fill($request->all())->save();
```

In both cases you're using [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment), so add all properties you're trying to update to `$fillable` array.

Comment: Thanks, in `save()` I get this error" `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()`

Comment: @MajAfy I've forgot to change `save()` to `update()` in the code, sorry. Fixed that.

Comment: Thanks, worked, but in result I get this error `Unknown column '_method' in 'field list'` I added `_method` to `$guarded`

Comment: @MajAfy try to do this `$request->except(['_method', '_token'])` instead of `$request->all()`

Comment: Thanks, work like a charm  , would you please add your comment to your answer ? so other users will understand what to do